# FindfirstEx using recursion

Tags: delphi

It drives me nuts (I'll should learn about recursion though)
But I'll can't make it work, something I'm doing wrong.

I was trying to make an exact copy of the FindFirst code below just with FindFirstEx but on the recursion I'll got stackoverflow and a lot of strange things happen so I'll guess that must be the wrong way using it so I'll removed it and replace it with the comment I'm stuck here...

So basically I'll need a procedure where I'm able to specify a directory and a file mask thats it.

```
procedure FetchFilesAndFolders(aPath, AMask; lbSearchResult: TMemo);
 const
  Find_First_Ex_Large_Fetch = 2;
  var
   hFile: Cardinal;
   searchResult: Win32_Find_DataW;
begin
  lbSearchResults.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  hFile := FindFirstFileEx(PChar(aPath + aMask), FindExInfoStandard, @searchResult,
FindExSearchNameMatch, nil, Find_First_Ex_Large_Fetch);

  If (hFile <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) Then
  begin
   try
  repeat
    If (searchResult.dwFileAttributes And faDirectory = faDirectory) Then
    begin
      lbSearchResult.Lines.Append(IncludeTrailingBackSlash(aPath) +
        string(searchResult.cFileName));
    end
    else
      begin
        // I'm stuck here...
    end;
  until (not FindNextFile(hFile, searchResult))
    finally Winapi.Windows.FindClose(hFile);;
  lbSearchResult.Lines.EndUpdate;
end;
```

Something like this but with FindFirstFileEx instead:

```
procedure FileSearch(const dirName, aMask: string; lbSearchResult: 
TMemo);
var
  searchResult: TSearchRec;
begin
  lbSearchResult.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  if FindFirst(dirName+ aMask, faAnyFile, searchResult) = 0 then
  begin
    try
      repeat
        if (searchResult.Attr and faDirectory) = 0 then
        begin
          lbSearchResult.Lines.Append(IncludeTrailingBackSlash(dirName) +
        searchResult.Name);
    end
    else if (searchResult.Name <> '.') and (searchResult.Name <> '..') then
    begin
      FileSearch(IncludeTrailingBackSlash(dirName) + searchResult.Name,
        lbSearchResult);
    end;
     until FindNext(searchResult) <> 0 finally FindClose(searchResult);
     lbSearchResult.Lines.EndUpdate;
    end;
  end;
 end;
```

So I'll need someone to show me doing it right.
Thank you!

**Version 3 (still not working but no exception):**

```
procedure FileSearch(const aPath, aMask: string; lbSearchResult: TMemo);
const
  Find_First_Ex_Large_Fetch = 2;
var
  hFile: Cardinal;
  searchResult: Win32_Find_DataW;
begin
  lbSearchResult.Lines.BeginUpdate;

  hFile := FindFirstFileEx(PChar(aPath + aMask), FindExInfoStandard,
    @searchResult, FindExSearchNameMatch, nil, Find_First_Ex_Large_Fetch);

  If (hFile <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) Then
  begin
    try
      repeat
        If (0 = (searchResult.dwFileAttributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) then
        begin
            lbSearchResult.Lines.Add(IncludeTrailingBackSlash(aPath) +
              string(searchResult.cFileName));
        end
        else
        begin
          If (searchResult.cFileName <> String('.')) And
            (searchResult.cFileName <> '..') Then
          lbSearchResult.Lines.Add(IncludeTrailingBackSlash(aPath) +
            string(searchResult.cFileName));

           // the following is not good, infinite!!!
          // FileSearch(aPath, aMask, lbSearchResult); 

        end;
      until (not FindNextFile(hFile, searchResult))
        finally Winapi.Windows.FindClose(hFile);;
      lbSearchResult.Lines.EndUpdate;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

All files and folders are shown which are inside the test folder but not any deeper so no recursion...

```
FileSearch('D:\projects\Test\', '*.*', Memo1);
```

So for example:

D:\projects\Test\Blubb

is shown but not the files inside or any directories from Test\Blubb\

Comment: Perhaps it would be more helpful to show us the code that causes the stack overflow. That after all is where you went wrong.

Comment: Failed.. Maybe it would be helpful to read the question again. If you look at the second code you know which code is causing the stack overflow because i've mentionend that I was trying to use the exact same code found as code 2 sample with FindFirstEx Well but especially for you this code causing the stackoverflow ....   FileSearch(IncludeTrailingBackSlash(dirName) + searchResult.Name,
        lbSearchResult);

Comment: Thanks for the sarcastic attempt at clarification, but the second code is a long way from the first, and if you look at the second code is specifically excludes the directory '.' which your code (we must assume) does not. The directory '.' is the current directory, which is the cause of your infinite loop.

Comment: Also '..' needs to be excluded because that is the parent directory, which would similarly cause an infinite loop.

Comment: That wasn't my intension to be sarcastic, excuse me... Still don't get it...

Comment: Maybe if you didn't start with "Failed", it wouldn't have been interpreted as sarcasm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of your infinite recursion appears to be that you are omitting the test for the files '.' and '..'.

in the second code there is the line

```
else if (searchResult.Name <> '.') and (searchResult.Name <> '..') then
```

These two values are special directories that mean 'current directory' and 'parent directory' respectively. So while analysing the current directory it will find a 'subdirectory' called '.', which is actually a pointer to the directory that you are currently analysing. Therefore a recursive call to this subdirectory will analyse the same directory again, during which it will again find the directory '.' and again attempt to analyse the same directory, and so on for ever.

A similar situation arises for '..' which would analyse the parent directory.

It is critical that this test not be omitted.

### Note on your version 3

One of my pet hates is not including begin...end blocks in if statements, and your 3rd version seems to illustrate why. You still get the infinite loop because your if statement does not apply to the recursion - which is exactly where it *must* apply.

The second, more serious issue is that the parameters of the recursive call are exactly the same as the original call. I can think of no circumstances where it is *ever* valid to do that (although I am sure that someone will correct me). Instead you must call with the name of the child directory. I have added a new variable fNewPath to simplify things.

```
procedure FileSearch(const aPath, aMask: string; lbSearchResult: TMemo);
const
  Find_First_Ex_Large_Fetch = 2;
var
  hFile: Cardinal;
  searchResult: Win32_Find_DataW;
  fNewPath : string;
begin
  lbSearchResult.Lines.BeginUpdate;

  hFile := FindFirstFileEx(PChar(aPath + aMask), FindExInfoStandard,
    @searchResult, FindExSearchNameMatch, nil, Find_First_Ex_Large_Fetch);

  If (hFile <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) Then
  begin
    try
      repeat
        If (0 = (searchResult.dwFileAttributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) then
        begin
            lbSearchResult.Lines.Add(IncludeTrailingBackSlash(aPath) +
              string(searchResult.cFileName));
        end
        else
        begin
          If (searchResult.cFileName <> String('.')) And
            (searchResult.cFileName <> '..') Then
          begin // <-------------------
            fNewPath := IncludeTrailingBackSlash(aPath) +
              string(searchResult.cFileName);
            lbSearchResult.Lines.Add( fNewPath );

            FileSearch(fNewPath, aMask, lbSearchResult);
          end; //<---------------  The recurstion *must* be covered by the if statement

        end;
      until (not FindNextFile(hFile, searchResult));
    finally Winapi.Windows.FindClose(hFile);
      lbSearchResult.Lines.EndUpdate;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: While following `'.'` is already bad enough, following `'..'` would theoretically be worse, as this would happen for all subdirectories of the parent. Fortunately, it never gets there, as it already gets stuck in the same directory. <g>

Comment: Yes, @RudyVelthuis I know, but I didn't want to labour the point ;-)

Comment: I was not entirely serious. Worse than infinite it can't get. I mean, 10 times infinity or even 1000 times infinity is still infinity. <g>

Comment: @dsm you're right bad habbit I have but even the corrected code you have shown produces a stackoverflow on this line: FileSearchFast(aPath, aMask, lbSearchResult);

Comment: @JohnDoe you are right - I missed a moore serious issue - now corrected.

Comment: Strange, while not getting a stack overflow exception anymore, nothing is added to the memo as before... when I comment out the problematic line I've got path and files added as before but not the subdirs + content of it... With problematic line I've ment: FileSearch...... Ok I'll could spot the problem FileSearch(IncludeTrailingBackSlash(fNewPath) ... works

Comment: @JohnDoe There should be a tick to the left of the answer that you can click. I think that I would move the Begin and end update outside the the function (itr shouldn't matter but it might) and also, to make it more general, I would pass a TStrings rather than a memo to the routine, and then pass TMemo.Lines rather than the TMemo. It just makes it simpler to use other things than a TMemo.

Comment: Makes really a difference in speed 18ms against 330ms

Comment: @dsm thank you found it ;) But there is one thing I'll don't get with that FindFirstEx when you use it on a really large directory e.g. system32 it works but the memo remains empty no exception thrown... other then that it works magically :) will try out more...

Comment: @JohnDoe There is a size limit on TMemo, that perhaps you are exceeding. I agree it should throw an exception, though, in this case, but I am not sure that it does.

Comment: You're right that can also be a problem, but for the moment I've spottet my mistake: BeginUpdate, EndUpdate wrong position... Works perfectly now!